# What is this time zone called?

Tags: earth-rotation, time

There is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and British Summer Time (BST). One is used in the United Kingdom (UK) in the winter, and the other in summer. Is there a three letter abbreviation for the time zone which means current UK time regardless of time of the year?

Comment: This might get a better response at English Language Learners Stack Exchange: http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Spencer I don't believe it would be on-topic at ELL.

Comment: It probably isn't on-topic anywhere, but the answer is No, there is no such three-letter abbreviation, much like CST/CDT, PST/PDT EST/EDT, CET/CEST and similar designations.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be edited to be more clear... but this question is about time zones, which is on topic.  The difference of GMT (no daylight savings) and British Summer Time (with Daylight savings) is worth answering on this site.

Comment: Closest I think we use is ET to refer to Eastern Time regardless of season in situations such as on television programming times.  But without multi-time zone programs over there, I never heard a similar term there.  Perhaps "British time" would be the fairest guess?  And while this doesn't fall under any of the sciences listed in the help, since there's no geography (yet), this seems a fair place to get an answer.

Comment: gis.stackexchange.com or even unix.stackexchange.com might be more helpful, but this is the Europe/London timezone (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London), and it doesn't have a single three digit abbreviation. It's GMT or BST, depending on the time of year. This is in contrast to American timezones like "MT" which means Mountain Time any time of year, more specifically MDT in the summer and MST in the winter.